# How to draw custom animation as Activity background

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, background, android-2.2-froyo

I have a standard Activity with its layout, and I have a custom animated View.

I want this View to permorm a fancy "intro" animation, after which the standard Activity is displayed with the animated View as a background.

The application should be compatible with froyo (2.2) devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a frame layout and insert two views, one is your custom view animation and the second one which will come on top would be your normal layout.